# How can I check if window.parent has properties

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web

At some point I need to check if `$window.parent` has properties.

Some times window.parent looks like this (it has a lot properties inside):

[image]

and some times like that (empty):

[image]

How can I check if `window.parent` has properties or it's empty?

Comment: Could you give us a little more context as to what you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: `window.parent` will always have properties ... a top level `window.parent === window` ... you can do `window.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent` etc it's self referencing :D